# Validation of a form - I'm getting the labels two times

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, twig

I have a registration form - from FOSUserBundle this is in the template:

```
{% form_theme form 'AcmeMyBundle:Form:errors.html.twig' %}

   <form class="big-spacer" action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register">
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <div>
            <input class="btn little-spacer" type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here is `errors.html.twig`:

```
{% block field_errors %}
    {% spaceless %}

        {% if errors|length > 0 %}

            <ul class="little-spacer nav text-error">
                {% for error in errors %}
                    <li>{{loop.index}}. {{ error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators') }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>

        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock field_errors %}
```

I have just added some css classes from TwitterBootstrap.

The problem is that I get some of the messages for the validation twice.

My form has 4 fields - **Username, Email, Password, Confirm Password**

I tried to break as many validation rules I can and here is the output:

For `Username`:

1. This username is already used. Please choose another one.
2. The username is too short - please enter at least 2 symbols.
3. The username is too short - please enter at least 2 symbols.

For `email`:

1. Please enter a valid email.
2. Please enter a valid email.

and if I enter already used email, the error is shown only once:

1. This email is already used.

And for the `passwords`:

If they are short:

1. The password is too short - please enter at least 6 symbols.
2. The password is too short - please enter at least 6 symbols.

And if they don't match:

1. The entered passwords don't match.

Another strange thing is that when I resubmit the form, but it's still not valid, the notice for the length of the password is only one:

1. The password is too short - please enter at least 6 symbols.

and before resubmitting, they were two.

Do you have any ideas why some of the errors are displayed twice and how to fix this? Thank you very much in advance! :)

---

**UPDATE**

This is `C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\src\Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User.php`

```
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

And in `C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\translations\` I copied the file `validators.en.yml` and in it and removed the `[-Inf, Inf]` part and changed the messages a bit.

I also overrode the validation file - I copied it here:

`C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\src\Acme\MyBundle\Resources\config\validation.xml`

I changed only the minimum length of the password. Everything else is the same as in the original file.

My bundle extends FOSUserBundle:

`C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\src\Acme\MyBundle\AcmeMyBundle.php` this file contains the following:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\BudgetTrackerBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeBudgetTrackerBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent() 
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you extends User entity from FOSUserBundle, and do you repeat validation rules on your extended entity ?

Comment: Mmm, yes, I think that I extend it.

Comment: Could you show your entity code ? If you re-define validation rules, it could be the reason of double error messages...

Comment: Of course I can. I updated my question. :)

Comment: You changed the minimum length in a translation file ?? I guess you changed something else to achieve this.. Any idea ? And, does your bundle extends FOSUserBundle ?

Comment: I'm sorry very much, my mistake and confusion, I updated the question again under **Update2**

Comment: Now, show your validation.xml ;) It probably comes from it !

Comment: Ok :) just a second. And thank you very much for the attention and the time you are spending trying to help me!

Comment: Your code snippet is expired. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, this is a known issue.

Let's have a look here : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2605

The solution is : create your own validation group for properties' validation rules you want to override. In your validation.xml, put only properties you want some different rules, and define validation on a new validation group.

So, for validation.xml, to modify only plainPassword validation rules for your entity (Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<constraint-mapping xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping
http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping/constraint-mapping-1.0.xsd">

    <class name="Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User"> 

        <property name="plainPassword">
            <constraint name="NotBlank">
                <option name="message">fos_user.password.blank</option>
                <option name="groups">Registration</option>
            </constraint>
            <constraint name="Length">
                <option name="min">6</option>
                <option name="minMessage">fos_user.password.short</option>
                <option name="groups">
                    <value>RegistrationAcme</value>
                    <value>ProfileAcme</value>
                </option>
            </constraint>
        </property>
    </class> 

</constraint-mapping>
```

And now you have to state that you use different validation groups for the impacted forms (registration and profile). Fortunately, FOSUserBundle is a good practices' example and allows you to override them in your config.yml :

```
fos_user:
    registration:
        form:
            validation_groups: [Default, RegistrationAcme]
    profile:
        form:
            validation_groups: [Default, ProfileAcme]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) It's perfect now, only it wasn't working with validation groups written with dashes and with RegistrationAcme, so I changed them to `[Registration, Default]` and `[ProfileAcme, Default]`

Comment: Finally a good and clear answer to this problem I've been searching a solution to for hours.

Comment: Hi @AlterPHP - Do you think you would be able to give me a hand with similar problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631172/duplicated-password-validation-messages)? I tried something similar to your answer above but failed to solve the problem. Highly likely I did something wrong/missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
# config.yml
# ...
fos_user:
    db_driver:     orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class:    Acme\YourBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: acme_user_registration
            validation_groups: [Registration]
# ...
```

Adding the last line ("validation_groups: [Registration]") results in only one error. Only FOSUserBundle validation: "Registration".