# How to override validation rules of FOSUserBundle

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-forms, fosuserbundle

My `ExampleUserBundle` extends `FOSUserBundle`. And I override `RegistrationFormType` like this :

```
<?php
// Example/UserBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php

namespace Example\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder->remove('username');
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'example_user_registration';
    }

}
```

Service's declaration :

```
// Example/UserBundle/Ressources/Config/services.yml
services:
    example_user.registration.form.type:
        class: Example\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: example_user_registration }
```

And in /app/config/config.yml :

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Example\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: example_user_registration
```

When I create a new `User` with this form, the basic validation rules of `FOSUserBundle` do not override. (email -> unique ; password -> more than 3 character ;  ...).

Answer (score 1):

The basic solution is to specify different validation group for registration form.

The solution worked for me: [Validation of a form - I'm getting the labels two times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501569/validation-of-a-form-im-getting-the-labels-two-times)

Answer (score 1):

i had similar problem but i want add new fiesld to my registration forms ,i work like this

also i should say that i used embed form in my overrided registration form

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
     $builder  
           ->add('avatar',FileManagerType::class,[
                "by_reference" => false,
                "data_class"=>File::class
            ])
            ->add('files', CollectionType::class,[
                "entry_type"=> UserFileManagerType::class,
                "allow_add" => true,
                "allow_delete"=>true,
                "by_reference"=>false
            ])

     public function getParent()
      {
         return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
      }
        public function getBlockPrefix()
      {
        return 'app_user_registration';
       }
```

and then in my embed forms i do like this

```
    class  FileManagerType extends AbstractType
    {

        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('file',FileType::class,[
                    "constraints"=>[
                        new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File([
                            "mimeTypes"=>["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/jpg"],
                            "groups"=>["Registration"]
                        ])
                  ]
                ]);

        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            //dump($resolver);
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => File::class
            ));

        }
    }
```

then in another embed forms

```
class UserFileManagerType extends AbstractType
{


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file',FileType::class,[
                "constraints"=>[
                    new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File([
                        "mimeTypes"=>["application/pdf", "application/x-pdf"],
                        "groups"=>["Registration"]

                    ])
                ]
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => File::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

now it is ready to work

Answer (score 0):

You can override validation rules of FosUserBundle by overriding the User attributes themselves.

Example: If I don't want the username to be required anymore, then I'll have to override the username in **AppBundle\Entity\User** (that extends the FosUserBundle User).

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\AttributeOverrides;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\AttributeOverride;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 *  @AttributeOverrides({
 *     @AttributeOverride(name="username",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(
 *             name="username",
 *             type="string",
 *             length=255,
 *             unique=false,
 *             nullable=true
 *         )
 *     ),
 *     @AttributeOverride(name="usernameCanonical",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(
 *             name="usernameCanonical",
 *             type="string",
 *             length=255,
 *             unique=false,
 *             nullable=true
 *         )
 *     )
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
//..
```

This code will make the username nullable in the database (after running `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`) **AND not required** in validation rules.